# How can I apply filter in odoo-10 tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a tree view, in odoo-10 that has almost 3000 records. But, I want to show only the records in tree view which has value **prod_def=3**.

The **last column** in image, it is "prod_def".

[image: Here is the image of my tree view.]

I tried in following way but it didn't work:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_multi_customer_names_tree">
        <field name="name">product.multi.customer.names.tree</field>
        <field name="model">product.multi.customer.names</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="domain">[('prod_def','=',3)]</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="label" />
                <field name="def_additional_val"/>
                <field name="prod_def" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Where is I am making mess didn't get. Help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't put the domain in view definition instead put it in the action definition. the action is the one responsible for loading the records if we can say this the view is just for showing information

Comment: Great! your comment solved my issue. Upvoted it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EasyOdoo You should post your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted to close this question. Include a link to the Actions documentation if you can.

Comment: @travisw thank you, I don't have time but you can post a better answer with more explanation